# can't save to NSUserDefaults on iOS 7.0.2

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults, foundation

In my app I use  NSUserDefaults and I updated my iPhone to the latest iOS 7.0.2. From then, the app doesn't save the data I wanted to be saved in NSUserDefaults.

I remember that from iOS 5 you had to ask the user for permission, does it the case?

The following code, save the forgot password status, i.e 'send your email' -> 'waiting for code' -> 'success'

The user insert his email and gets an email with a code, after inserting the code he get to set his new password.
My code is:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *temp = [defaults valueForKey:FORM_STATUS];
```

I have never needed to synchronise. The above code worked perfectly until IOS v7.0.2, and the bug is happening only on a real device. not on the simulator or a device with IOS 7.0.
Yesterday I have used my iPhone to check it and in the evening I updated my device and checked again.

If someone remember from IOS 5 if you didn't ask permission to use the photos you couldn't see the modal view. I remember creating an app on that time that used the user photo library and it stopped working on a real updated device (on that time).

Comment: Show your code. What do you get when you load the defaults instead?

Comment: Ask for permission to save to `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: You should not need permissions for storing data in NSUserDefaults AFAIK.

Comment: I guess this is yet another "you have to call `- synchronize`" question.

Comment: -synchronize should not be necessary except in cases of abnormal termination. Note that 'abnormal' includes the 'stop' button in the debugger, and termination due to memory pressure.

Comment: (i.e. it's likely still a *good idea* to call it on iOS devices, but it shouldn't be necessary for it to work at all)

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report at bugreport.apple.com, NSUserDefaults didn't change behavior in 7.0.2 so it's likely that some component of the system underneath it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Store :

```
NSString * Authkey = @"Sivarwin";
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:Authkey forKey:@"Key"];
NSLog(@"SYMBOL : %@",Authkey);
```

To Retrieve:

```
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loginString = [storeData valueForKey:@"Key"];
NSLog(@"%@ Saved String ",loginString);
```

Comment: Your code should work so I'll mark it as answered. But I guess the problem was the iOS version (it was beta at the time)